# Can AsyncRetrieve class in Android have results that are not Strings from PHP echo?

Tags: java, php, android

Below is the Async class that my Android application uses in Java to receive results from PHP pages. For example, to login, the PHP is called with variables, and the php will echo "Success" or something else. The Java receives that STRING and decides if(result="success") then proceed and etc.

However, I have a PHP page that is echoing out a JSON object for the Java to use, however, Async is set up for Strings. I can't just change the onPostExecute to have (JSON result) rather than (String result) so what is the process? is this possible?

```
private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(TodayActivity.this);
HttpURLConnection conn;
URL url = null;
JSONObject client;

//this method will interact with UI, here display loading message
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

// This method does not interact with UI, You need to pass result to onPostExecute to display
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String username = params[0];

    try {
        // Enter URL address where your php file resides
        url = new URL("https://URLGOESHERE####.php");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
    try {

        // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //MY STUFF HERE
        OutputStream OS = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");

        bf.write(data);
        bf.flush();
        bf.close();
        OS.close();



    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return e1.toString();
    }

    try {

        int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

        // Check if successful connection made
        if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            // Read data sent from server
            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            // Pass data to onPostExecute method
            return (result.toString());

        } else {

            return ("unsuccessful");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }


}

// this method will interact with UI, display result sent from doInBackground method
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    pdLoading.dismiss();

    Toast.makeText(TodayActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: will the `result` not be the text of the JSON result - then use a JSON Parser

Comment: *if(result="success")* - I am sure you do not mean that